# magento 2 - Actions column link to external URL such as google.co.uk?

Tags: magento2, column, action

I have the below code for a Action column option:

```
$item[$name]['view'] = [
    'href' => 'www.google.co.uk',
    'target' => '_blank'
    ),
    'label' => __('View')
];
```

What I'm trying to do is add an external URL to an action column such as google.co.uk. It should open a new tab and displays Google's home page.

Currently, the code provided appends www.google.co.uk to the Magento page URL.

Could you please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Try with full URL, so add the "http://" in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$item[$name]['view'] = [
   'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('http://www.google.co.uk'),
   'target' => '_blank'
  ),
 'label' => __('View')
];
```